# ERROR realm = plugin>com.sun.jersey.contribs:maven-wadl-plugin:1.17

Tags: java, rest, maven, maven-3, jira

I am using Maven 3.3.3 and I have this error. I read about this error here [Jersey maven-wadl-plugin cannot resolve HttpServletRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766084/jersey-maven-wadl-plugin-cannot-resolve-httpservletrequest) but I not fixed with servlet-api as a direct dependency and external maven.

Here is the message:

```
[ERROR] realm = plugin>com.sun.jersey.contribs:maven-wadl-plugin:1.17` 
  Execution generate of goal com.sun.jersey.contribs:maven-wadl-plugin:1.17:generate failed:
  A required class was missing while executing com.sun.jersey.contribs:maven-wadl-plugin:1.17:generate:
  Lcom/atlassian/extras/common/log/Logger$Log
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm = plugin>com.sun.jersey.contribs:maven-wadl-plugin:1.17
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Desarrollo/maven_repo/com/sun/jersey/contribs/maven-wadl-plugin/1.17/maven-wadl-plugin-1.17.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Desarrollo/maven_repo/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/2.0.9/apache-maven-2.0.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Desarrollo/maven_repo/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.9/maven-reporting-api-2.0.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Desarrollo/maven_repo/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Desarrollo/maven_repo/junit/junit/4.8.2/junit-4.8.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Desarrollo/maven_repo/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.0/commons-cli-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Desarrollo/maven_repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Desarrollo/maven_repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.1/plexus-utils-1.5.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Desarrollo/maven_repo/xerces/xercesImpl/2.6.1/xercesImpl-2.6.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Desarrollo/maven_repo/com/sun/jersey/jersey-servlet/1.17/jersey-servlet-1.17.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Desarrollo/maven_repo/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.17/jersey-server-1.17.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Desarrollo/maven_repo/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Desarrollo/maven_repo/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.17/jersey-core-1.17.jar
```

This is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin.aem-mur</groupId>
    <artifactId>aem-mur-rest-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <organization>
        <name>Project Name</name>
        <url>http://www.testrest.com/</url>
    </organization>
    <name>service-rest</name>
    <description>test rest</description>
    <packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.sal</groupId>
            <artifactId>sal-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- WIRED TEST RUNNER DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.testrunner.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2-atlassian-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins.rest</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-rest-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
            <artifactId>wink-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3-incubating</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                    <groupId>jta</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.refapp</groupId>
                <artifactId>atlassian-platform</artifactId>
                <version>${refapp.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-refapp-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${amps.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <productVersion>${refapp.version}</productVersion>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>atlassian.org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation</name>
                            <value>sun.*,com.sun.*</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- GENERATE WADL -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-wadl-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.17</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <wadlFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/aem-mur.wadl</wadlFile>
                    <formatWadlFile>true</formatWadlFile>
                    <baseUri>http://localhost:9999/jira/rest</baseUri>
                    <packagesResourceConfig>
                        <param>com.test.jira.aemmurrestservice</param>
                    </packagesResourceConfig>
                    <wadlGenerators>
                        <wadlGeneratorDescription>
                            <className>com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorApplicationDoc</className>
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>applicationDocsFile</name>
                                    <value>${basedir}/src/main/doc/application-doc.xml</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                        </wadlGeneratorDescription>
                        <wadlGeneratorDescription>
                            <className>com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorGrammarsSupport</className>
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>grammarsFile</name>
                                    <value>${basedir}/src/main/doc/application-grammars.xml</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                        </wadlGeneratorDescription>
                    </wadlGenerators>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Build the JAR with dependencies -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <refapp.version>2.19.2</refapp.version>
        <amps.version>5.0.18</amps.version>
        <plugin.testrunner.version>1.1.2</plugin.testrunner.version>
        <jira.version>6.3.9</jira.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fixed the problem, with atlassian-extras library.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>atlassian-extras</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```